# How do I import .R or .r files into Evernote as notes?

Tags: import, attachments, r, evernote, textfiles

I have many r files that I'd like to be able to keep and search in Evernote, so importing them as notes would be great.

Importing them as attachments doesn't let me search them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bulk import .r or .R files into Evernote:

Move/copy all your R script files to a new folder (eg Import).

Open command line and set the directory as the new folder, and change the file extension from .R to .txt:

```
CD C:\Import ren *.r *.txt
```

Open Evernote. Navigate to Tools>Import folders
and add the new folder (Import)

Occasionally, some files may have special characters that Evernote doesn't like. In these cases, take note of the problem text and search for it with windows search. You should be able to locate the problem files and replace the characters.

Done!

Comment: Does your folder name contain space? If yes then you've to add folder path with double quote.

Comment: True, took out the spaces